# Controlling when snaps update

Tags: updates, snap

I was listening to the latest latenightlinux and there it [was mentioned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GXcxX9zm9I#t=30m49s) that the snapd deamon has some kind of systemd integration that auto updates snaps. I am wondering how I can have more fine control over that on my system.

Is it integrated with the Software and Updates > Automatically check for updates option? Does that mean that if I set automatic updates to never the snaps will never update unless I do a `sudo snap refresh`? Or will they still update?

Does anyone know how it is possible for a user to configure this?

Note: My system is up-to-date Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: This is discussed in the snap forum under: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/disabling-automatic-refresh-for-snap-from-store/707

Comment: Yes, found out about it and already made a post there. Not sure what to do here though. I don't want to write shady workarounds like blocking access to update servers as has been posted there. I will update/answer if an official option comes after a new snapd version.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering how I can have more fine control over that on my system.

You can fine tune when snaps update by editing the refresh schedule via the command:

```
sudo snap set core refresh.schedule={time-frame (24 hr time)}
```

You can only set the refresh schedule within a 24hr time-frame though.

An example would be:

```
sudo snap set core refresh.schedule=4:00-7:00/19:00-21:00
```

This will set the refresh schedule to only between 4-7 AM to 7-9 PM.

However if you haven't updated recently snapd might forcible update outside of the specified time-frame.

> Does that mean that if I set automatic updates to never the snaps will never update unless I do a sudo snap refresh? Or will they still update?

No, it will still automatically update unless you edit the 24hr time-frame in which it updates unless you want to mess around blocking the updating servers in the iptables.

Comment: [Here's a reference](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-schedule-via-core-config/434) for the current functionality. Scheduling beyond 24 hours is coming, follow the discussion [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/refresh-scheduling-on-specific-days-of-the-month/1239/11).

Comment: While I appreciate the effort of the developers to allow for this scheduling I do not really like them as a user. They make sense for a server and system admininstrator's perspective or for a desktop that a user treats as an appliance. But not from a user's perspective where he wants to own his system. I want to be in control of my system and update whenever I am in front of it to watch what has been updated and be able to give attribution if something breaks after the update.

Comment: Note that the Snap developers are still discussing the best way to control updates on the desktop. If you want to _respectfully_ voice your opinions, please [join the discussion on the snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/re-visiting-update-control-on-the-desktop/17170).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options to control updates, depending on what you want exactly.

### An update broke my application!

Run `snap revert package-name` to go back to the previous version of that application. You will stay on that version until the next version of the app gets released. If the next version is broken too, you can run `snap revert` again.

### I want to stick with an older version of the app

Many software in the snap store uses [tracks](https://snapcraft.io/docs/channels) for major software releases. Most snaps default to using the `latest/stable` track, which will give you the latest updates of the application once they are released but users can choose a different track to stick with a specific version.

For the CLion IDE, for example, you can see the supported tracks by running `snap info clion`. You can switch to a different track by running `snap refresh clion --channel=2020.2/stable`. You will stay on that track until you manually change to a different track. You will still get automatic updates for the application but depending on which track you choose, you will only get the minor updates for that specific version of the software.

Publishers decide whether or not to enable tracks in their snap, so if a snap you like doesn't have a track for the version you need, be sure to contact the publisher!

### I want to check updates before I install them

In this case, you probably want to change the refresh timer. For example, the following option sets the refresh timer to the last Friday of the month, from 23:00 to 1:00 the next day. This gives you a lot of time to check the updates and install them manually.

```
sudo snap set system refresh.timer=fri5,23:00-01:00
```

You can use the CLI tools or the snap store to see which updates are available.

### I want to hold all updates until after my big presentation

The "hold" option is what you need. You specify an exact date and snap will hold any updates until that date. For example, this holds updates for the next 30 days.

```
sudo snap set system refresh.hold="$(date --date='today+30 days' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%:z)"
```

*Note: the maximum number of days you can hold updates for is 60.*

### I want to disable updates when I'm paying for my download bandwidth

By default, snap will not update when NetworkManager detects a metered connection such as an LTE/3G/4G. If NetworkManager does not detect it correctly, [you can set it manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364932/87565).

### I want to do something else!

See the [Controlling updates](https://snapcraft.io/docs/managing-updates#heading--controlling-updates) docs for more options.

Do need another configuration option? Join the discussion in [how to control snap updates on the desktop](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/re-visiting-update-control-on-the-desktop/17170).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. It will be a useful reference for snap users. Unfortunately it is not what I am looking for as I say in the question. I was looking for a solution where the default action is don't upgrade unless the user does something (e.g. give permission on a prompt). You can do this with deb packages but not with snaps in Ubuntu. This is a simple solution that keeps the mental bandwidth needed for maintaining one's system on the low end. Unfortunately Canonical have decided to not add this functionality.

Comment: @Karsus most Snap developers do not want to introduce a "turn off all updates forever" to avoid the current issue with insecure Ubuntu desktops because the `apt` updates are not applied.

If you read through [controlling snap updates on the desktop](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/re-visiting-update-control-on-the-desktop/17170), however, you'll see a Canonical employee proposing the "turn off all updates, forever" option. I think it's useful for you to go on that thread and talk about what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I have already replied to that thread ;)

Comment: There should be an option to turn off updates, and another option to manually hold particular package in some version forever. Otherwise it is WINDOWS 10 approach to users.

Comment: @Wojtas.Zet if you want this to become a reality, please reply to the thread I linked. Adding a comment on askubuntu will not achieve much. You need to talk to the actual Snap developers.